# Using NSMutableArray to get objects doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I created an NSMutableArray and inside it I put a UISlider. For some reason though, whenever I try to get its value, i.e.

```
[[sliderArray objectAtIndex:index] value];
```

it comes out as an NSString * but when I try

```
[slider value];
```

it comes out as a float. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you're seeing as the result of these calls? It's not quite clear to me what you mean. The same method will be run in both cases -- if the object is a `UISlider` at runtime, then it's a `UISlider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know what kind of object will be retrieved when you use `objectAtIndex`. You need to typecast the returned object so that it knows you're talking about a `UISlider`.

```
[(UISlider *)[sliderArray objectAtIndex:index] value];
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid now. I tried type casting it but I put it OUTSIDE the brackets haha. Thank you so much kind stranger!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
UISlider *slider = [sliderArray objectAtIndex:index];
[slider value];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the UISlider from the array:

```
UISlider *slider = [sliderArray objectAtIndex:index];
[slider value];
```

or cast it

```
[(UISlider *)sliderArray[index] value];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)[sliderArray objectAtIndex:index];
[slider value];
```